# Accessing model data inside a controller in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to access data in my Model for my controller method.

For starters what is the difference between these two???

```
$post = $this->Post->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>$id)));

$this->set(compact('post'));
```

and

```
$this->Post->id = $id;

$this->data = $this->Post->read();
```

as I'm trying to compare the user_id for a post against the logged in user like so:

`if($this->Post->user_id != $this->Auth->user('id'))`

but it doesn't work as intended (it always returns false)... what is the difference between the two code chunks and why doesn't my line above work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
$post = $this->Post->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>Tiny::reverseTiny($id))));

        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))
        {
            $this->Post->id = $post['Post']['id'];
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated');
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Server broke!');
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if($post['Post']['user_id'] != $this->Auth->user('id'))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Not yours!');
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
            else
            {               
                $this->request->data = $this->Post->read(null, $post['Post']['id']);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

test to see if it helps to compare this code "userid":

```
function index() {

   $user_id = $this->data['Post']['user_id'];
   if($user_id != $this->Auth->user('id')){
    //go
   }

}
```

Comment: Remember to call in your controller to Auth: var $components = array('Auth');

Comment: The issue is not with the Auth! It's a problem with `$this->Post->user_id` is that even valid code?

Comment: in cakePhp 2.0 de code is: $this->request->data = $this->Post->read(null, $id);

Comment: If I do debug($this->Post->user_id) I get nothing as it's empty because it doesn't know what Post is! Which is what my question is about and how does the two methods differ and why.

Comment: the difference between the two methods, read () is used to set the data of the current model, while editing and find () is to find one or more results. When you do the debug ($this->Post->user_id)? before or after ($this->Post->id = $ id;)?, if earlier, it is normal not get anything

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between `find()` and `read()`, read will grab all related model data and set the active record of the model to the result. Whereas a find will just all related model data in a query and assign the result to the variable.

Use `debug($this->data)` to reveal the structure of your returned data. You will find it is `$this->data['Post']['user_id']` for the User ID.

Comment: My question was what's the difference between the find() and `$this->Post->id = $id;` as they both set the current entity based on the passed ID.

Comment: @Cameron that's what my first paragraph addresses... Find will fetch, where as read will fetch and set the active model. Read the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data#read-1029

Comment: No! I understand the difference between find and read!! My QUESTION was what is the difference between finding the post via the id and just setting the id against the model like: `$this->Post->id = $id;`